# After setting up fail2ban w/Permanently Ban Repeat Offenders to fail2ban - I'm not be getting any emails of bans w/detailed info anymore

Tags: email, fail2ban, ubuntu-16.04

After installing fail2ban 0.9.3 on my uBuntu server 16.04 and then following the steps located from this link - [Perma Ban Repeat Offenders](https://wireflare.com/blog/permanently-ban-repeat-offenders-with-fail2ban/) I did service fail2ban reload and got the emails showing the services stopped and started.  but,  I seem to not be getting emails showing what ip address has been banned and the detailed information that I use to get. I use to get these emails like all the time.

Here's a link to view my jail.conf and jail.local files

[Link to jail local and conf files](http://drops.articulate.com/18XUm)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I just had to wait it out as I just got an email with an ip address and the details from jail2ban.

Issue resolved.